# Продвижение приложений

Tags: android, маркетинг

Здравствуйте.

Решил заняться продвижением своего приложения, но опыта совсем нет.
Хотелось бы услышать толковые советы по поводу того, где можно разместить обзоры на приложение, использовать ли Admob в качетсве рекламы и т.п.

На данный момент у меня есть только опубликованный обзор на [4pda.ru](http://4pda.ru/2013/03/20/93633/) и соответствующая тема на форуме. Приложение ориентировано на русскоязычных пользователей.

**UPD**

Тематика: медицина. Денег особо тратить не хочется, потому что не уверен что они потом мне вернутся обратно ибо приложение бесплатное, но с рекламой

Comment: что за приложение? тематика? целевые пользователи? бюджет?

Comment: Можно ссылку на обзор? Так с ходу план раскрутки и не составишь

Comment: добавил ссылку на обзор на 4pda

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопросы по маркетингу и раскрутке не относятся к тематике StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

**Полезное** приложение раскрутится и без пиара :)

1. приложения хорошо раскручиваются под события (например, сделать приложения для 1 мая - в этот период будут хорошие закачки)
2. 4пда - хороший ресурс для раскрутки русскоязычных приложений
3. обзоры и статьи - практически не влияют на закачки (разве что хаброэфекты)
4. икона должна быть привлекальной
5. на хабре полно хороших статей по раскрутке

Comment: иногда открываю google play, смотрю какое убожество в топе находится в разделе социальных например и плакать хочется. пиар просто многое решает

Comment: вообще, мир несправедливая штука

Answer (score 1):

Да при такой редкой тематике тяжело вам будет.

Лучший вариант - договариваться с больницами, аптеками и др.

А вообще попробуйте поступить так: предложить аптекам выкупить ваше приложение. Аптеки тоже   не против иметь свой каталог. Сумеете договориться - аптечники попросят вставить пару иконок, добавить пару лекарств и др. И готово - с вас приложение (вместе с исходным кодом), а с них деньги. Только подбирайте рекламную сеть покрупнее, и настаивайте на сумме >500 000